# Insert new XML node using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

XML:

```
<Questions>
   <Question>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Text>aaa</Text>
      <Reserver />
   </Question>
   <Question>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Text>bbb</Text>
      <Reserver />
 </Question>
</Questions>
```

How can insert new Question using LINQ like this:

```
<Question>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Text>ccc</Text>
      <Reserver />
 </Question>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Questions>...</Questions>");
doc.Root.Add(
    new XElement("Question",
        new XElement("Id", 3),
        new XElement("Text", "ccc"),
        new XElement("Reserver"))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new element like this:

```
var newElem = new XElement("Question",
    new XElement("Id", 3),
    ...
);
xdoc.Root.Add(newElem);
```